# Rails 3 - how to update my migrations by DB schema

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, migration, schema

I updated my DB schema a I would need to update a migrations by this schema.
Exist any elegant way to do it or I have to update my migrations manually?

Thank you

Comment: Would you explain your problem more clearly?

Comment: if I will run the command `rake db:schema:dump`, so I will get current DB schema. And from this schema I need to generate new migrations. But I don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't generate migrations from the `schema.rb` file. Instead, use `rails generate migration`, or generate them as part of your models.

Comment: thanks Marnen for your reply, but I need to create a migrations. I have an app, I have the schema of database, but I by mistake deleted the migrations of tables from my DB.

Comment: Uh, what? Do you mean that you need to *run* the migrations? I cannot understand what you're asking. Please explain in more detail.

Comment: Well, I deploy my app to server and for creating the database on a server are using migrations. But my problem is, that I have not these migrations. And I don't know, what to do now...

Comment: `rake db:schema:load` will create the DB from the schema file. Is that what you want?